# How to show only next line after the matched one?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

```
grep -A1 'blah' logfile
```

Thanks to this command for every line that has 'blah' in it, I get the output of the line that contains 'blah' and the next line that follows in the logfile. It might be a simple one but I can't find a way to omit the line that has 'blah' and **only** show next line in the output.

Comment: I think many people will come here looking for the `-A1` option

Comment: Then I use this to get my public IP. :) `curl whatismyip.org | grep -A1 'Your IP Address'`

Comment: Similarly -B1, -B2, -B3, -A1, -A2, -A3  . . .

Comment: @shrek curl http://icanhazip.com (no grep needed) :)

Comment: Your **question** answered my question ... `-A1`.  Thanks!

Comment: WARNING: many of the solutions assumes 1/ Only a single match is in file, OR 2/ matching lines are well seperated (not next to each other)

Answer (score 216, accepted):

you can try with awk:

```
awk '/blah/{getline; print}' logfile
```

Comment: For anyone who really wanted a grep -A2 equivalent (which is what I needed), getline just eats the line and goes on to the next.  So what worked for me was literally just `awk '/blah/{getline; getline; print}' logfile`

Comment: I loved this getline solution.

Comment: WARNING: Assumes you do not get two matching lines next to each other

Comment: And that the last line of the document isn't matching

Answer (score 209):

If you want to stick to grep:

```
grep -A1 'blah' logfile | grep -v "blah"
```

or alternatively with sed:

```
sed -n '/blah/{n;p;}' logfile
```

Comment: @Kent, thanks for the tip. From my POV though, grep is much more readable and easy to grasp compared to sed or the awk answer marked as best answer....but it's just me maybe :)

Comment: For those curious about what -v does:
-v
  --invert-match
  Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines. (-v is specified by POSIX.)

Comment: I really like this answer, but it won't work if you have two lines in a row containing "blah" and want to get the second one (because it's "the next line after the matched one").  I can't think of any use case for that off the top of my head, but it's worth noting.

Comment: The top solution is merely "ok". If the second line happens to have "blah" in it as well, you'll have a real mess on your hands.

Comment: WARNING: Assumes you do not get two matching lines next to each other.  The "grep will then have extra "--" lines, while the "sed" skips lines.
BUT I find this "sed" solution the most useful when that is not the case.

Comment: the "sed" option is pretty useful for many use cases

Answer (score 39):

Piping is your friend...

Use `grep -A1` to show the next line after a match, then pipe the result to `tail` and only grab 1 line,

```
cat logs/info.log | grep "term" -A1 | tail -n 1
```

Comment: If "term" is on the last line, this will return the line containing "term" instead of nothing, what you would want.

Comment: tail -n 1 will only result last line of whole file

Answer (score 14):

Great answer from raim, was very useful for me. It is trivial to extend this to print e.g. line 7 after the pattern

```
awk -v lines=7 '/blah/ {for(i=lines;i;--i)getline; print $0 }' logfile
```

Answer (score 13):

Many good answers have been given to this question so far, but I still miss one with `awk` not using `getline`.  Since, [in general](http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline), it is not necessary to use `getline`, I would go for:

```
awk ' f && NR==f+1; /blah/ {f=NR}' file  #all matches after "blah"
```

or

```
awk '/blah/ {f=NR} f && NR==f+1' file   #matches after "blah" not being also "blah"
```

The logic always consists in storing the line where "blah" is found and then printing those lines that are one line after.

#### Test

Sample file:

```
$ cat a
0
blah1
1
2
3
blah2
4
5
6
blah3
blah4
7
```

Get all the lines after "blah". This prints another "blah" if it appears after the first one.

```
$ awk 'f&&NR==f+1; /blah/ {f=NR}' a
1
4
blah4
7
```

Get all the lines after "blah" if they do not contain "blah" themselves.

```
$ awk '/blah/ {f=NR} f && NR==f+1' a
1
4
7
```

Comment: This is a good solution that handles consecutive matching lines, in the two possible ways...   Up voted for completeness!

Answer (score 12):

If that next lines never contain 'blah', you can filter them with:

```
grep -A1 blah logfile | grep -v blah
```

The use of `cat logfile | ...` is not needed.

Comment: If you don't like "cat" but want the filename at the start of a complex pipeline, try this  `<logfile grep -A1 blah | grep -v blah`
It is perfectly valid BASH!

Answer (score 7):

I don't know of any way to do this with grep, but it is possible to use awk to achieve the same result:

```
awk '/blah/ {getline;print}' < logfile
```

Comment: @jww There is no difference. As you can see from the timestamps that are just minutes apart, it appears that I answered around the same time.

Answer (score 6):

In general, I agree you're asking a lot of grep here, and that another tool may be the better solution. But in an embedded environment, I may not want to have `sed` or `awk` just to do this. I found the following solution works (as long as they're not contiguous matches):

```
grep -A1 AT\+CSQ wvdial.out | grep -v AT\+CSQ
```

Basically, match them, appending 1 line of context for each match, and then pipe that through an inverse match of your original pattern to strip those out. This of course means you can assume that your pattern doesn't show up in the "next" line.

Comment: WARNING: It also outputs the '--' seperators on multiple matches.

Answer (score 4):

*perl one-liner alert*

just for fun... print only one line after match

```
perl -lne '$. == $next && print; $next = ($.+1) if /match/' data.txt
```

even more fun... print the next ten lines after match

```
perl -lne 'push @nexts, (($.+1)..($.+10)) if /match/; $. ~~ @nexts && print' data.txt
```

kinda cheating though since there's actually two commands

Comment: Can you explain $.==$next? Clearly it's more than a numeric comparison of the current line number with $next, but I don't understand how/why it works.

Comment: It's not any more than that. `$. == $next && print` is the same as `print if $. == $next`

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thx! Of the 2 parts, each is true and executes on separate, adjacent iterations of the loop. I suppose if the point was to print any line after any match that you would want to reverse the order (would behave more like `grep -A1`). If you want to print only next lines but never a line with a match, then you would keep it this order. (just noting how $next would be clobbered for consecutive matches)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using the wrong tool there.  Grep isn't that sophisticated, I think you want to step up to awk as the tool for the job:

`awk '/blah/ { getline; print $0 }' logfile`

If you get any problems let me know, I think its well worth learning a bit of awk, its a great tool :)

p.s.  This example doesn't win a 'useless use of cat award' ;)
http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: BTW, you can skip "$0" in print.

Answer (score 2):

you can use grep, then take lines in jumps:
`grep -A1 'blah' logfile | awk 'NR%3==2'`

you can also take n lines after match, for example:
`seq 100 | grep -A3 .2 | awk 'NR%5==4'`
15
25
35
45
55
65
75
85
95
explanation - 
here we want to grep all lines that are *2 and take 3 lines after it, which is *5.
`seq 100 | grep -A3 .2` will give you:
12
13
14
15
--
22
23
24
25
--
...
the number in the modulo (NR%5) is the added rows by grep (here it's 3 by the flag -A3), +2 extra lines because you have current matching line and also the -- line that the grep is adding.

Answer (score 0):

grep /Pattern/ | tail -n 2 | head -n 1

Tail first 2 and then head last one to get exactly first line after match.

Comment: This only handles one match

Answer (score 0):

You can match multiple lines and output n lines after with:

```
awk 'c&&!--c;/match1/{c=1};/match2/{c=2}' file
```

Match multiple items and output n lines after:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -z $3 ] && echo $0 file \[match n\]+... \# to output line n after match && exit
f=$1; shift; while [ \! -z $2 ]; do s="$s/$1/{c=$2};"; shift; shift; done
awk 'c&&!--c;'$s $f
```

So you can save the above as `matchn.sh` and `chmod +x matchn.sh` and then if you have a file like this:

```
line1
line2 
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
```

And run:

```
./matchn.sh file line1 1 line3 2 line6 1
```

You will get:

```
line2
line5
line7
```

This will need a bit more tweaking to support 0 offsets.

Answer (score 0):

With grep you could output the line number (`-n`). By that the output differs between the match and the next line through `<num>:` and `<num>-`:

```
# grep -A1 -n '230 Login successful."$' /var/log/vsftpd.log
1:Sat Nov  5 03:29:43 2022 [pid 10] [foo] FTP response: Client "10.1.1.1", "230 Login successful."
2-Sat Nov  5 03:29:43 2022 [pid 10] [foo] FTP response: Client "10.1.1.1", "221 Goodbye."
3:Sat Nov  5 04:44:41 2022 [pid 10] [foo] FTP response: Client "10.1.1.1", "230 Login successful."
4-Sat Nov  5 04:44:42 2022 [pid 10] [foo] FTP response: Client "10.1.1.1", "221 Goodbye."
```

By that we are able to filter the output to get only the next line of each match:

```
# grep -A1 -n '230 Login successful."$' /var/log/vsftpd.log | grep -E "^[0-9]+-" | cut -d"-" -f2-
Sat Nov  5 03:29:43 2022 [pid 10] [foo] FTP response: Client "10.1.1.1", "221 Goodbye."
Sat Nov  5 04:44:42 2022 [pid 10] [foo] FTP response: Client "10.1.1.1", "221 Goodbye."
```