# Print line after a specific contained word line in UNIX

Tags: parsing, unix, printing, line, cpu-word

I have problem, I want to parse a log file, I want to print a line if the above line is containing a specific word,

for example

```
line 1 containing : aaa

line 2 containing : bbb
```

so, it will print out bbb

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451423/grep-a1-how-to-show-only-next-line-after-the-matched-one may have what you need

Answer (score 1):

The `-A n` option to `grep` prints the next `n` lines after the matching line.

```
grep -A 1 aaa logfile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the 'aaa' printed as well, you could use sed(1):

```
sed -n '/aaa/{n;p}'
```

Explanation:

```
-n    don't print every line
/aaa/ when this pattern is matched, execute the block that follows
n     advance to the next line
p     print what's in the buffer
```