# Search a particular string for the first time in the file and print and subsequent lines in unix and similar for next time

Tags: shell, unix

Okay.I will be very specific with what I want.I need to write a script a which processes a numerous files and it has following type of xmls in those files:

```
<NotificationList>   
    <Name>Postpaid</Name>
    <Amount>5.0</Amount>
    <IsRecurring>0</IsRecurring>
    <ThresholdLimit>5.0</ThresholdLimit>
    <ObjectType>1</ObjectType>
    <subscription>1010984</subscription>
    <NotificationTime>2018-05-> 
    31T00:18:46.000000+01:00</NotificationTime>
```

I need to get the name, subscription, NotificationTime for each of the xml in column wise.
I am able to print these values in rows one below the other by doing 
grep -A 8 "" * | grep 'name\|subscription\|NotificationTime'

Hope am clear this time.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: you can use vi in unix - it must be there and it has macros - all you need (good tutorials on vi here: http://derekwyatt.org/vim/tutorials/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show only next line after the matched one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451423/how-to-show-only-next-line-after-the-matched-one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by

`grep -e name -e subscription -e NotificationTime filename.txt | cut -d ">" -f2 | cut -d "<" -f1 | paste -d , - - -`

Using paste command you can print multiple searched patterns into a line with any specific delimeters.

Description
"paste -- :
Combining N consecutive lines: The paste command can also be used to merge N consecutive lines from a file into a single line. Here N can be specified by specifying number hyphens(-) after paste."

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by

```
grep -rnw '/path/to/file/file.format' -e "Hello this is the"
```

If you are inserting the notification from other command in text file you can add comment to make it easy to search for or syntax of the notification like shown above.

```
#You can add comment for notification which will make it easy to find all notifications by tag.

#Hello notification
Hello instance 1
#Navigation notification
Turn right instance 1
#Hello notification
Hello instance 2
```

**EDIT:**
I think what Tom Fenech linked is what you are looking for. If indeed it is, it is a duplicate question.