# R grep() return whole matching line (similar to the unix grep -A -B?)

Tags: r

I've been searching for a way to ask grep to return a whole line for a matching pattern. Is there functionality for this in R's grep()? I am imagining something like the [unix grep arguments -An](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451423/how-to-show-only-next-line-after-the-matched-one)

Some context: For a paper I've written I want to create a data table or a vector of all citations in a paper. Extracting everything in the paper thats within parentheses using `qdapRegex::rm_round()` sometimes only returns a year (in the case of citations written like: *'As put forth by Smith (2020)'*). It would be nice to grab the whole sentence instead of just *'2020'*.

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Sure, that's fairly straightforward, depending on your input data. Can you share sample data and your expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` has an argument `value` which you can set as `TRUE` to get the whole string back.

Consider this example where you are looking for numbers.

```
x <- c('This is 2022', 'This is not a year', '2021 was last year')
grep('\\d+', x)
#[1] 1 3
```

By default `grep` returns an index where a match is found.

If you need the complete string as an output -

```
grep('\\d+', x, value = TRUE)
#[1] "This is 2022"       "2021 was last year"
```

Comment: Great, I will try to use this! I was definitely misunderstanding the function of the value argument. I appreciate the clarification on this.

Answer (score 1):

```
s <- c("As put forth by Smith (2020)",
       "As put forth by Smith 2020",
       "As put forth by Smith",
       "As put forth (Smith 2020)")

s[grep(pattern = "\\(.*\\)", x = s)]
#> [1] "As put forth by Smith (2020)" "As put forth (Smith 2020)"

Created on 2022-01-14 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```